# Textmate - search data in directory

Tags: macos, osx-lion, textmate, textmatebundles

Can i search data in directory? It's too painful to search on whole project (on my Mac it takes something like 5-15 minutes which is awful). Version of textmate is 1.5.10 (1631).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, TextMate does not support searching in a specific folder. This is soon to change though, with the current [alpha release of version 2.0](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/textmate-2-0-alpha/) adding in this support.

So, to search within a specific folder inside TextMate 1.5, you have 2 options:

1. Create a new project for the folder you want to search in (you can do this quickly by dragging and dropping the desired folder on to the new project button)
2. Create your own 'Find in Folder' command, by going to `Bundles` > `Bundle Editor` > `Show Bundle Editor (⌃⌥⌘B)`. From here, you can click on the `'+'` button at the bottom and create a new command. [See here](http://snipplr.com/view/21360/) for an example of how to create a find in folder command.